# how to identify the boundary conditions for functions with two or more variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I got given an optimisation problem and was asked to find an initial set of equations that represent the problem along with four boundary conditions. How do I find boundary conditions? Are critical points and boundary points the same thing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Critical points and boundary points are not the same thing. Look wikipedia article Critical point (mathematics).